# Embedding matrix and one hot vector (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, one-hot-encoding, word-embedding

I derived a Bidirectional LSTM for Sentiment analysis on news headlines, but when training the model the loss function value doesn't improve, stays around 0.6 and 0.7.
Certainly I'm making something wrong, I wonder if it is something related with the Embedding layer.

I'm iteratively passing each batch into the Network with a size of 10 and sentence length of 30 words, my vocabulary size is 5745 so the shape of this tensor would be (10, 30, 5745) after one hot encoding.

My Embedding layer has num_embeddings = 5745 and embed-dim = 100 so when I call self.embedding(input), have as output shape: (10, 30, 5745, 100)

I wanted to have an output shape of: (10,30,100)

Therefore I used this line of code:

```
        embeddings = torch.max(embeddings, dim=2)
```

But I'm not sure if it does what I expect it to do for each word/one-hot vector which is:

if I have one hot encoding vector representing a word with shape (5745,1) and an embbeding matrix with shape  (100, 5745), I get an embedding vector of (100,1) and therefore I would have an ouptut of (10,30,100) by doing the above code?
Maybe I'm not thinking correctly and it's affecting my end result

RNN:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, n_layers, dropout):
    #calling the init function of the RNN parent
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim)
    
    self.encoder = nn.LSTM(embed_dim,
                           hidden_dim,
                           n_layers,
                           dropout=dropout,
                           bidirectional=True
                          )
    
    #Linear transformation
    self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, output_dim)
    
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    

def forward(self, inputs):
   
    #(batch_size, timesteps, embed_dim)
    embeddings = self.dropout(self.embedding(inputs))
    embeddings = torch.max(embeddings, dim=2)
    embeddings = embeddings[0].type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

    #output of each timestep
    output, (hidden, cell) = self.encoder(embeddings)
    
   
    merge = self.dropout(torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim=1))
   
    output = self.decoder(merge)
    
    return output
```

train:

```
def train(model, text, label, epochs, lr=0.001):

model.train()

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
#The BCEWithLogitsLoss criterion carries out both the sigmoid and the binary cross entropy steps
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

counter = 0
for e in range(epochs):
    for x, y in batches(text, label):
        
        #In order to avoid gradient accumulation before backpropagation
 
        
        x = one_hot_encode(x, vocab)
        
        x = torch.from_numpy(x).to(device)
        
       
        
      
        output = model(x)
       
       #print(torch.cuda.memory_summary(device=None, abbreviated=False))
       
        y = torch.from_numpy(y)
       
        y = torch.unsqueeze(y,1).to(device)
        #print(output.shape)
        #print(y.shape)
        
        loss = criterion(output, y.float())
       
        acc = binaryAccuracy(output,y)
        
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        
        
        counter += 1
        
    print("Epoch {}/{}".format(e+1, epochs), 
        "Loss: {}".format(loss.item()),
        "accuracy: {}".format(acc))
```

one-hot:

```
def one_hot_encode(arr, n_labels):


one_hot = np.zeros((np.multiply(*arr.shape), n_labels), dtype=np.int64)

one_hot[np.arange(one_hot.shape[0]), arr.flatten()] = 1

one_hot = one_hot.reshape((*arr.shape, n_labels))

return one_hot
```

batches:

```
def batches(text, label, num_seqs=10):

counter = 0
#create empty arrays with the specified number of columns 
x = np.array([], dtype=int).reshape(0,findMaxLen())
y = np.array([], dtype=int).reshape(0,1)

for sent, l in zip(text, label):
    # create a np array with zeros with length 30
    tmp1 = np.zeros((findMaxLen()), dtype=int)
    #tmp1 = np.randint(0, high=vocab,size=findMaxLen(), dtype=int)
    #create a 1d array
    tmp2 = np.atleast_1d(np.array(l))
    
    for ind, wrd in enumerate(sent):
        if wrd in uniqueWrds and ind < 30:
            tmp1[ind] = word_to_index[wrd]
    # the arrays to the empty arrays
    x = np.vstack([x, tmp1])
    y = np.vstack([y, tmp2])
    counter +=1
    if counter == num_seqs:
        yield x, np.squeeze(y,1)
        counter = 0
        x = np.array([], dtype=int).reshape(0,findMaxLen())
        y = np.array([], dtype=int).reshape(0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to be of dimension (10,30,100), I think you need to input the indexes of the words of the sentences in the form of an array of dimension (10x30). You can probably get the indexes by performing a [torch.argmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html) on the one hot encoded input tensor.